# Sidemenu collapse not working using Angular module

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, side-menu

I've integrated an sb-admin template in my angular project. So, I divided that into modules like Sidebar, footer etc. Where I'm facing the problem with collapsing a Sidebar. **If I insert sidebar using a module, *menu collapse* doesn't work and if I move that `<nav>` directly to `<body>` in *index.html*, it works!**

Here's my code -

***sidebar.component.html -***

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light sakon-header fixed-top" id="mainNav">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">
        <img style="height:30px" src="assets/images/sakon-logo-horizontal.png" />
    </a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive"
        aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-sidenav sakon-sidebar" id="exampleAccordion">
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

***index.html -***

```
<body>
    <app-root>
    </app-root>
    <!-- if nav moved here, it works -->
</body>
```

So, I *want it working with a Sidebar module*.

> Update: project structure for ref. -

```
- app
    - pages
    - theme
        - components
            - sidebar
                - sidebar.component.css
                - sidebar.component.html
                - sidebar.component.ts
    - app.component.css
    - app.component.html
    - app.component.ts
    - app.module.ts
- index.html
```

Comment: can you share your project structure

Comment: I just updated it, please check it above!

Comment: does your app.component.ts contain something like this `@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',

})`'

Comment: yeah, it's the same!

Comment: I don't see any routing component here.

Comment: to my understanding, you need that sidebar present all the time no matter you change the component.

Comment: Exactly! My layout is fixed all the time, but only the content changes as per routes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166385/discussion-between-abhishek-ekaanth-and-tushar-walzade).

Answer (score 1):

To this you need to add app.routing.ts

```
 - app
    - pages
    - theme
        - components
            - sidebar
                - sidebar.component.css
                - sidebar.component.html
                - sidebar.component.ts
    - app.component.css
    - app.component.html
    - app.component.ts
    - app.module.ts
    - app.routing.ts
 - index.html
```

in your `app.routing.ts` you need to add something like this.

```
export const AppRoutes: Routes = [{
    path: '',
  component: SidebarComponent,
  children: [
  {path: 'ROUTING PATH', loadChildren: 'COMPONENT_PATH'}]}]
```

in your `app.component.ts` should be like

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'
})
```

Comment: I already did it this way -
`{ path: '', component: SecureComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard], children: SECURE_ROUTES }`

Comment: RouterModule.forRoot(AppRoutes) is added in your `app.module.ts`

Comment: Yeah, it is added.

Comment: still can't figure out where you might be going wrong, currently, I'm working on same which works exactly same.